# email not being sent when customer group is changed via admin

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I know this has been asked before although the code to do this was not so clear and so I have the below code setup however no email is being sent and wondering what step I might of missed. Basically I want to when an admin inside Magento changes a customer to a different customer group and clicks save I then want to send the customer an email.

app/etc/modules/groupidemailnotice.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
      <modules>
          <groupidemailnotice>
             <codePool>local</codePool>
             <active>true</active>
             <depends>
               <Mage_Catalog />
             </depends>
          </groupidemailnotice>
      </modules>
   </config>
```

app/code/local/groupidemailnotice/etc/config.xml

```
<global>
   <events>
      <customer_save_after>
         <observers>
             <groupidemailnotice>
                 <type>singleton</type>
                 <class>magento37890/observer</class>
                 <method>checkDisplay</method>
             </groupidemailnotice>
          </observers>
      </customer_save_after>
   </events>
</global>
```

app/code/local/groupidemailnotice/Model/Observer.php

```
    <?php
       class Stackexchange_Magento37890_Model_Observer
          {
            public function checkDisplay(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
             {

                $customer=$observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
                Mage::log('My log entry'.$customer->getId(), null, 'Magento37890.log');
                 /* if customer  is old customer */
                 if($customer->getId())
                 {
                     if($customer->getOrigData('group_id')!=$customer->getData('group_id')){
                     /* here you write your code to send whenever you have change the group */
                     mail("$customer->getEmail","approved","Yay your approved");
                     }
                 }else{
                 /* New Customer */

             }
         }

        }
```

?>

When I look at the `system.log` I see the below error

> Notice: Undefined index: customer_group_id  in /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php on line 1780

But why would the observer not be able to get the customer group id??

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with this :

```
<adminhtml>
        <events>
            <adminhtml_customer_save_after>
               <observers>
                     <groupidemailnotice>
                         <type>singleton</type>
                         <class>Stackexchange_Magento37890_Model_Observer</class>
                         <method>checkDisplay</method>
                     </groupidemailnotice>
              </observers>
            </adminhtml_customer_save_after>
        </events>
 </adminhtml>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many things you are doing wrong here.
First your Module naming is incorrect. You cannot use `groupidemailnotice` as your module name.
 You module is related to Customer so it should depend on `Mage_Customer`.
 You can create a new module with name `Groupid_Emailnotice` and create a file **app/etc/modules/Groupid_Emailnotice.xml** with below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Groupid_Emailnotice>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
      <depends>
        <Mage_Customer />
      </depends>
    </Groupid_Emailnotice>
  </modules>
</config>
```

The `config.xml` file you created is also not at correct location. It should be on `app/code/local/NAMESPACE/MODULENAME/etc/config.xml`. So, Now add a config file in **app/code/local/Groupid/Emailnotice/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Groupid_Emailnotice>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Groupid_Emailnotice>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <events>
      <adminhtml_customer_save_after>
        <observers>
          <send_email_to_customer>
            <type>model</type>
            <class>Groupid_Emailnotice_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>sendMailNotice</method>
          </send_email_to_customer>
        </observers>
      </adminhtml_customer_save_after>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

Now create an observer in **app/code/local/Groupid/Emailnotice/Model/Observer.php**

```
<?php
class Groupid_Emailnotice_Model_Observer
{
    public function sendMailNotice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $customer=$observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        Mage::log('My log entry'.$customer->getId(), null, 'Magento37890.log');
         /* if customer  is old customer */
        if($customer->getId())
        {
            if($customer->getOrigData('group_id')!=$customer->getData('group_id')){
            /* here you write your code to send whenever you have change the group */
                mail("$customer->getEmail","approved","Yay your approved");
            }
        }else{
         /* New Customer */
        }
    }   
}
```